# GXT - send forms on enter, project-wide

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

I have an application which uses GXT and contains ±30 forms. I would like to make these forms so that when the user hits enter in a text field, the form gets submitted, like a regular browser form would.

I know I can add a key press listener to every text field, which would invoke the submit after enter is pressed, but since I want to apply this to every field in every form I am not sure if this is ideal.

Is there a simpler way to implement this in the entire application?

If not, which pattern should I use to add this functionality to every field? I can extend the TextField class, add the functionality in the child class and use the child class in the application. Or I can create a factory for the text field class which would also add the listener to the field. Or is there some other way, Decorator perhaps? I was wondering which of these approaches, if any, is generally preferred.

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like this:

```
    Event.addNativePreviewHandler(new NativePreviewHandler() { 
      @Override 
      public void onPreviewNativeEvent(NativePreviewEvent event) { 
        if (event.getNativeEvent().getKeyCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_ENTER) { 
          if (event.getNativeEvent().getEventTarget() != null) { 
            Element as = Element.as(event.getNativeEvent().getEventTarget());
            if (as.getTagName().toLowerCase().equals("input") ||
                as.getTagName().toLowerCase().equals("textarea")) {
              // TODO submit data;
            }
          } 
        } 
      } 
    });
```

Every time someone hits the Enter Key and the cursor is placed on a input- or textarea-tag, you will get the control and can submit your data.

Comment: Another way to do this could be to add the dom handler to a parent element, possibly as high as the root element (probably RootPanel, etc). Downside: this would give you enter events other than in those specific elements (though you could easily create that same logic), upside: other widgets could prevent the enter key from bubbling up (such as when you are in an expanded combo box, datepicker, etc).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to do what you're asking directly in the GXT library. I do want to stress that extending the TextField class just to add an event handler to it is not the correct way to handle this. Event handlers are based on the composition of a class. It would be like extending a class with a List field just to add another element into the list.

A singleton factory class that created and initialises the Textfield for you would be the cleanest solution, in my opinion. It would allow you to effectively change defaults and add other handlers as required at a later time in a single place if requirements change.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it with `GWT JSNI` also.

Steps to follow:

- define a function in `JavaScript` that is called on `Enter` key press
- call `GWT JSNI` from above JavaScript function that is exported at the time of `onModuleLoad` using `GWT JSNI`
- get the Element from where this event is triggered and finally submit the form based on its tag name or Id

**Sample code:**

HTML/JSP:

```
<script>
    window.onkeydown = keydown;

    function keydown(event) {
        if (event.which == 13) {
            formSubmit(event.target);
        }
    }
</script>
```

JAVA(Entry Point):

```
import com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element;
public void onModuleLoad() {        
    exportFormSubmit();
    ...
}

public static void formSubmit(Element element) {
    Window.alert("element tag name:" + element.getTagName() + "form ID:"
            + element.getParentElement().getId());
}

public static native void exportFormSubmit() /*-{
   $wnd.formSubmit = $entry(@com.x.y.z.client.GWTTestProject::formSubmit(Lcom/google/gwt/dom/client/Element;));
}-*/;
```